# iOS NavController title question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Currently, all of my titles for different views are being correctly rendered from this:

```
self.title = self.viewedCategory.title;
```

However, because of the data structure, there is no title for the main root view.  I tried to fix it with this:

```
if (self.viewedCategory.title == Nil) {
    self.title = @"Root View Title";
} else {
    self.title = self.viewedCategory.title;
}
```

But that doesn't work and I'm not sure why.  I also tried '== @""' thinking that it might be a string without any chars, but that didn't work either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to compare strings is to use isEqualToString. So:

```
[self.viewedCategory.title isEqualToString:@""];
```

But a better and more convenient way to test if a string is empty or nil is with:

```
[aString length] == 0;
```

This will be true for @"" and for nil because [nil length] returns 0

Answer (score 0):

To see if an NSString is empty do this

```
[myString isEqualTo:@""];
```

This will return a bool value as either `YES` or `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

If You Compare Two String that time below code are used

```
bool isCompare = [currentString isEqualTo:@"CompareString"];


if (isCompare)
{
//Do For Comparing
}
else
{
//Do For Not Comparing
}
```